# AWS API Gateway routes request to $default instead of route

Tags: amazon-web-services, sockets

I am using an AWS Websocket API Gateway that has the following routes:

[image]

I've been able to connect to my websocket and send requests and receive responses from /SendMessage with the following json: `{"action": "SendMessage", "message":  "Hello, World"}` however, when I tried adding a new route /Register. Sending the json `{"action": "Register", "message":  "Hello, World"}` AWS API Gateway routes the request to `$default`.

The following request appears on CloudWatch:

[image]

The request should be routed to /Register and not /default. Do I need to do some kind of redeployment of the API Gateway when I add a new route?

Comment: Have you deployed your changes?

Comment: Yes, I've deployed from API->Routes->Actions->Deploy API @noninertialframe

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you have re-deployed your API Gateway.
Second, make sure you have re-deployed your Lambda functions

Last, you have to Stringify your request like this:

```
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({
        "action": "SendMessage",
        "message":  "Hello, World"
    }))
```